# Asp email submission with file attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code but it does not work - I get errors when using a `message.To` then I changed it to `message.To.Add` but without any success.

I don't know ASP.net, I just want this thing to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
using System.Net.Mail;


protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string body = "";
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    body = "<table border='0' align='center' cellpadding='2' style='border-collapse: collapse' bordercolor=''#111111' width='100%' id='AutoNumber1'>";
    body = body + "<tr><td width='100%' align='center' colspan='6'><b>Photo Submission Form</b></td></tr>";
    body = body + "<tr><td width='100%' colspan='6'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    body = body + "<tr><td width='50%' colspan='2'>Name</td><td width='50%' colspan='4'><b>" + name.Text + "</b></td></tr>";
    body = body + "<tr><td width='50%' colspan='2'>E-Mail</td><td width='50%' colspan='4'><b>" + email.Text + "</b></td></tr>";
    body = body + "<tr><td width='50%' colspan='2'>Caption</td><td width='50%' colspan='4'><b>" + caption.Text + "</b></td></tr>";
    body = body + "<tr><td width='50%' colspan='2'>Phone</td><td width='50%' colspan='4'><b>" + phone.Text + "</b></td></tr>";
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    Attachment myAttachment = new Attachment(FileUpload1.FileContent, fileName);
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("contact@xxxx.com"));
    message.From = New MailAddress(email.Text);
    message.Subject = "Photo Submission Form";
    message.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
    message.Body = body;
    message.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);
    SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert(0, "");
    SmtpMail.Send(message);
    RegisterStartupScript("startupScript", "<script language=JavaScript>alert('Message sent successfully.');</script>");
```

Comment: You need to learn C# and ASP **.Net**.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> The Attachment class is used with the MailMessage class. All messages
> ```
>
> include a Body, which contains the
>   content of the message. In addition to
>   the body, you might want to send
>   additional files. These are sent as
>   attachments and are represented as
>   Attachment instances. To add an
>   attachment to a mail message, add it
>   to the MailMessage.Attachments
>   collection.
>
> ```
> Attachment content can be a String, Stream, or file name. You can
> ```
>
> specify the content in an attachment
>   by using any of the Attachment
>   constructors.
>
> ```
> The MIME Content-Type header information for the attachment is
> ```
>
> represented by the ContentType
>   property. The Content-Type header
>   specifies the media type and subtype
>   and any associated parameters. Use
>   ContentType to get the instance
>   associated with an attachment.
>
> ```
> The MIME Content-Disposition header is represented by the
> ```
>
> ContentDisposition property. The
>   Content-Disposition header specifies
>   the presentation and file time stamps
>   for an attachment. A
>   Content-Disposition header is sent
>   only if the attachment is a file. Use
>   the ContentDisposition property to get
>   the instance associated with an
>   attachment.
>
> ```
> The MIME Content-Transfer-Encoding header is represented by the
> ```
>
> TransferEncoding property.

```
        public static void CreateMessageWithAttachment(string server)
        {
            // Specify the file to be attached and sent.
            // This example assumes that a file named Data.xls exists in the
            // current working directory.
            string file = "data.xls";
            // Create a message and set up the recipients.
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
               "jane@contoso.com",
               "ben@contoso.com",
               "Quarterly data report.",
               "See the attached spreadsheet.");

            // Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
            Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
            // Add time stamp information for the file.
            ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
            disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
            disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
            disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
            // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
            message.Attachments.Add(data);

            //Send the message.
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
            // Add credentials if the SMTP server requires them.
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

  try {
              client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                       //Handle...

            }

            data.Dispose();
        }
```